# Create an array of Nullable objects with different underlying type?

Tags: c#

I have a number of nullable objects of different types (e.g. `DateTime?`, `Guid?`) that I want to check for a value.

I'd like to avoid code like this:

```
return SomeGuid.HasValue || SomeBool.HasValue || SomeDateTime.HasValue
```

but it does not seem possible to create an array of `Nullable<object>`. I was hoping to do something like:

```
return new Nullable<object>[] { SomeGuid, SomeBool, SomeDateTime }.Any(o => o.HasValue);
```

Comment: Why not just box the items into a `List<object>`? You don't necessarily need `Nullable<T>` if all you want to do is test for a value inside a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object` is nullable per definition.

So the following works:

```
Guid? guid = null;
bool? boolean = null;
DateTime? date = DateTime.Now;

var test = new object[] { guid, boolean, date }.Any(o => o != null);
```

Do note `Nullable<T>` requires `T` to be a `struct`, i.e. a *value* type (not a *reference* type). `object` is a *reference* type.

Comment: So `Nullable<T>.HasValue` and `Nullable<T> == null` are functionally equivalent?

Comment: @BenFoster `HasValue` is the same as `!= null`

Comment: @BenFoster notice that except the syntactic sugar of C# that the != null is 'parsed' to .HasValue (when the compile time type is Nullable), ken2k has shown another trick: The boxing operations performed at the array creation assign null instead of boxed nullable objects. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A little complicated, but you can wrap the nullable objects using a uniform interface, as follows:

```
interface INullableWrapper
{
    bool HasValue { get; }
    object Value { get; } // Careful: boxing!
}

class NullableWrapper<T> : INullableWrapper
    where T : struct
{
    public T? Nullable { get; private set; }

    public bool HasValue { get { return this.Nullable.HasValue; } }

    object INullableWrapper.Value { get { return this.Nullable.Value; } }

    public T Value { get { return this.Nullable.Value; } }

    public NullableWrapper(T? nullable)
    {
        this.Nullable = nullable;
    }
}

return new INullableWrapper[] { new NullableWrapper<int>(5), new NullableWrapper<string>("Hello") };
```